# Iterating over arrays Check if an array contains two numbers

Tags: java, arrays, integer, pattern-matching

Write a program that reads an unsorted array of integers and two numbers `n` and `m`. The program must check if `n` and `m` occur **next to each other** in the array (in any order).

#### Input data format

- The first line contains the *size* of an array.
- The second line contains *elements* of the array.
- The third line contains two integer numbers `n` and `m`.

All numbers in the same line are separated by the *space* character.

#### Output data format

Only a single value: `true` or `false`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int size = scanner.nextInt();
        int[] table = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
            table[i]=scanner.nextInt();
        }
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        int m = scanner.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < table.length ; i++) {
            //stuck here 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You first need to find m or n. And then check if the neighboring elements are n or m respectively.

Comment: Are you familiar with `if` statements?

Comment: Instead of leaving a comment `// stuck here` you could __write pseudo-code__ as comments, or try some implementation and state, why this is not working, a [example]. The we can help you to transport your ideas to proper code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it can help you:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < table.length-1 ; i++) {
            if (table[i] == m){
                if (table[i+1] == n) {
                    System.out.println("true");
                    return;
                }
            }
            if (table[i] == n){
                if (table[i+1] == m) {
                    System.out.println("true");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("false");
```

Comment: Don't just give them answer right away. Especially without explaining. Are you going to help them every time they get stuck?

Comment: You could help the OP by explaining your test-algorithm (what are the `if`s testing). When changing the for-loop (upper-limit/exit-condition to `table.length-1`), why is it required here?

Answer (score -1):

This will pass all tests:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int arraySize = scanner.nextInt();
        int[] array = new int[arraySize];

        for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
            array[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }

        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        int m = scanner.nextInt();
        boolean valuesAreNotOccurNearEachOther = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
            if (array[i] == n || array[i] == m) {
                if (array[i + 1] == m) {
                    valuesAreNotOccurNearEachOther = false;
                }
                if (array[i + 1] == n) {
                    valuesAreNotOccurNearEachOther = false;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(valuesAreNotOccurNearEachOther);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is a great idea to specify some test-cases (which OP, didn't). Can you list the tests (that your code passes)? What happens if `n` is repeated twice in array (true or false) ? What makes your code different from [dev55555's one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67510962/5730279)?\

Comment: 9
3 4 5 6 3 4 6 4 4
4 4